# Writing files to a user directory temporary folder using Java in Websphere 9

Tags: java-8, websphere, tomcat8

I have an application which has multipart file attachment module. In this, I have created a logic which writes the files to the local application server(Tomcat in my case) temp folder and gets deleted once it has been uploaded.

I used this logic for creating files,

```
File tmpFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.install.root") + File.separator + file.getOriginalFilename());
        file.transferTo(tmpFile);
```

This works as expected in Tomcat, but deploying the same in Websphere 9 environment, throws the below exception,

> [11/13/17 20:20:45:946 IST] 000000f2 SystemErr     R Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program
>   Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer_1\profiles\AppSrv01\temp\WIN7VSNode04\server1\project name\project name.war\null\tmpfiles\uploaded file.extension
>   (The system cannot find the path specified.)

What might be the issue here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is null when you're concatenating the path:

```
...\project name.war\null\tmpfiles\...
                     ^^^^
```

Fix that and it should probably work.

Comment: No, "null\tmpfiles" path exists under websphere directory but not under the mentioned path, the path is "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer_1\profiles\AppSrv01\null\tmpfiles"